# Unity auto-redirection of view to the location where the selected button is

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

My project is containing a panel in which it contains a scroll_area with scollrect and rect mask 2d. In children, There is a gameobject containing vertical layout. And finale there is a list of button in which the six first elements are in 2 rows of three button and the rest is below in each individual panel. Every ancor is at the middle, and I want to move the gameobject containing vertical layout to the location where eventSystem seleted element is. I have try this code from multiple researches, but for some reason, it will go at the bottom of the panel before going to the location of the button after a long time for the next update to lauch, but I didn't the frameRate of update. Can you tell me how to fix this error with the correct code? Here is my code that I have try with a display of what I meant :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using static AmmoManager;
using static SaveManager;

public class UIManagerWorkshop : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] TMP_Text moneyPlayer;
    [SerializeField] Image[] bars;
    [SerializeField] Button[] colorButtonsToBuy;
    [SerializeField] Button[] upgradeButtonsToBuy;
    [SerializeField] TMP_Text[] priceTexts;
    [SerializeField] TMP_Text[] stockTexts;
    [SerializeField] Image errorMoneyLowerThanPrice;
    [SerializeField] ScrollRect scrollRect;
    [SerializeField] RectTransform content;
    [SerializeField] RectTransform maskTransform;
    private const float displayDuration = 2;


    private int numberItems;
    private GameObject previousSelectedObject;
    private EventSystem eventSystem;
    private Outline previousOutline;

    public enum BarType
    {
        Shielding,
        Attack,
        Velocity
    }

    public enum ButtonType
    {
        Color1,
        Color2,
        Color3,
        UpgradeShield
    }


    private void Awake()
    {
        UpdateMoneyPlayer();
        UpdateStockAmmo();
        eventSystem = FindFirstObjectByType<EventSystem>();
        UpdateButtonSelection(eventSystem.firstSelectedGameObject);

    }


    private void UpdateStockAmmo()
    {
        foreach (AmmoType ammoType in Enum.GetValues(typeof(AmmoType)))
        {
            SetStocks(ammoType);
        }
    }

    public void UpdateMoneyPlayer()
    {
        moneyPlayer.text = "Argent : " + WalletManager.Instance.getCurrentMoney() + "$";
    }

    void Update()
    {
        UpdateButtonSelection(eventSystem.currentSelectedGameObject);
    }

    private void UpdateButtonSelection(GameObject currentSelectedGameObject)
    {
        if (currentSelectedGameObject.CompareTag("ElementShop"))
        {
            OnButtonSelected(currentSelectedGameObject);
        }

    }

    public void OnButtonSelected(GameObject currentSelectedGameObject)
    {
        //Debug.Log(scrollRect.name + " " + content.name + " " + maskTransform.name);
        var itemAnchorPositionInScroll = scrollRect.transform.InverseTransformPoint(currentSelectedGameObject.transform.position);
        //but must be here
        var targetAnchorPositionInScroll = scrollRect.transform.InverseTransformPoint(maskTransform.TransformPoint(Vector2.zero));
        //so it has to move this distance
        var difference = targetAnchorPositionInScroll - itemAnchorPositionInScroll;
        difference.z = 0f;

        difference.z = 0f;
        //we move the content to align the item at the correct position
        var newAnchoredPosition = content.parent.InverseTransformPoint(content.position + difference);

        newAnchoredPosition.x = content.anchoredPosition.x;

        content.anchoredPosition = newAnchoredPosition;

        if (previousOutline == null || previousOutline.gameObject != currentSelectedGameObject)
        {
            // Remove outline from the previous outlined object
            if (previousOutline != null)
            {
                DisableOutline(previousOutline.gameObject);
            }
            // Enable outline for the currentSelectedGameObject
            EnableOutline(currentSelectedGameObject);
            // Update the previous outlined object
            previousOutline = currentSelectedGameObject.GetComponent<Outline>();
        }
    }
    private void EnableOutline(GameObject obj)
    {

        Outline outline = obj.GetComponent<Outline>();
        if(outline != null)
        {
            outline.enabled = true;
        }

    }

    private void DisableOutline(GameObject obj)
    {
        Outline outline = obj.GetComponent<Outline>();
        if (outline != null)
        {
            outline.enabled = false;
        }
    }


    public void ModifyBar(BarType barType, float currentValue, float maxValue)
    {
        int index = (int)barType;
        ModicationBar(bars[index], currentValue, maxValue);
    }

    private void ModicationBar(Image barToModify, float currentValue, float maxValue)
    {
        barToModify.fillAmount = currentValue / maxValue;
    }

    public void RemovePriceAndListener(ButtonType buttonType)
    {
        int index = (int)buttonType;
        if (index >= 0 && index < colorButtonsToBuy.Length)
        {
            ChangeButtonToModifyColor(colorButtonsToBuy[index]);
        }
        else if (index >= colorButtonsToBuy.Length && index < colorButtonsToBuy.Length + upgradeButtonsToBuy.Length)
        {
            ChangeButtonToModifyUpgrade(upgradeButtonsToBuy[index - colorButtonsToBuy.Length]);
        }
    }

    private void ChangeButtonToModifyColor(Button button)
    {
        Destroy(button.GetComponentInChildren<TMP_Text>());
        Destroy(button.GetComponent<OnClickBuyItem>());
        button.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        button.AddComponent<OnClickModifyColorTank>();
    }

    private void ChangeButtonToModifyUpgrade(Button button)
    {
        Destroy(button.GetComponentInChildren<TMP_Text>());
        Destroy(button.GetComponent<OnClickBuyItem>());
        button.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        button.GetComponent<OnClickModifyUpgradeTank>().enabled = true;
    }

    public void SetPrice(ButtonType buttonType, int price)
    {
        int index = (int)buttonType;
        if (index >= 0 && index < colorButtonsToBuy.Length)
        {
            SetPrice(colorButtonsToBuy[index], price);
        }
        else if (index >= colorButtonsToBuy.Length && index < colorButtonsToBuy.Length + upgradeButtonsToBuy.Length)
        {
            SetPrice(upgradeButtonsToBuy[index - colorButtonsToBuy.Length], price);
        }
    }

    private void SetPrice(Button button, int price)
    {
        button.GetComponentInChildren<TMP_Text>().text = price + "$";
    }

    public void SetPricePerUnit(AmmoType priceType, int price)
    {
        int index = (int)priceType;
        if (index >= 0 && index < priceTexts.Length)
        {
            SetPricePerUnit(priceTexts[index], price);
        }
    }

    private void SetPricePerUnit(TMP_Text priceUnitText, int price)
    {
        priceUnitText.text = "Prix par unité: " + price.ToString() + "$";
    }

    public void SetStocks(AmmoType stockType)
    {
        int newValueStock = 0;
        int index = (int)stockType;
        switch (stockType)
        {
            case AmmoType.Mines1:
                newValueStock = Instance.GetAmmo(AmmoType.Mines1);
                break;
            case AmmoType.Mines2:
                newValueStock = Instance.GetAmmo(AmmoType.Mines2);
                break;
            case AmmoType.Mines3:
                newValueStock = Instance.GetAmmo(AmmoType.Mines3);
                break;
            case AmmoType.Projectiles2:
                newValueStock = Instance.GetAmmo(AmmoType.Projectiles2);
                break;
            case AmmoType.Projectiles3:
                newValueStock = Instance.GetAmmo(AmmoType.Projectiles3);
                break;
        }
        SetStocks(stockTexts[index], newValueStock);
    }

    private void SetStocks(TMP_Text stockUnitText, int newValueStock)
    {
        stockUnitText.text = "En inventaire: " + newValueStock.ToString();
    }

    public void DisplayErrorMoneyMessage()
    {
        StartCoroutine(DisplayImage());
    }

    IEnumerator DisplayImage()
    {
        errorMoneyLowerThanPrice.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(displayDuration);
        errorMoneyLowerThanPrice.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

[image: image glitch]

Comment: My bad, it was a error of update that sould be change to Late update